# QRcode using ZXing (Issue with Error Correction)

Tags: asp.net, vba, vb.net, qr-code, zxing

Here is the code for ASP.net, this script run on a IIS (QR_Code.aspx)

OS: Windows 10 PRO

```
<%@ Page language="vb" debug=true %>
<%@ Import NameSpace = "Zxing.Interop.Encoding.BarcodeWriter" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace = "System.IO" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace = "System.Drawing" %>

'-----------------------------------------------'
'QR-Code
'-----------------------------------------------'
Dim ZX As New ZXing.BarcodeWriter
Dim bmp As Bitmap

Zx.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
Zx.Options.Height = 250
Zx.Options.Width = 250
Zx.Options.Margin = 0.9
Zx.Options.PureBarcode = True
Zx.Format = 2048

bmp = Zx.Write("Test_1234")
bmp.Save("c:\inetpub\wwwroot\tester\qrcode.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
'-----------------------------------------------'
```

The above code is working just fine but my problem is that I'm unable to find any correct reference for the "Error correction" for the above code.

I've tried the following code but no luck!

```
Zx.Options.ErrorCorrection = ErrorCorrectionLevel_H
```

or

```
Zx.ErrorCorrection = ErrorCorrectionLevel_H
```

or

```
ErrorCorrection = ErrorCorrectionLevel_H
```

Keep getting this error message from the browser

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'ErrorCorrection' is not a member of 'ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions'.
```

For your information:

```
Filename: zxing.dll
File Description: Zxing.net for 3.5
File Version: 0.16.4.0
Sha256 Hash: e1ed37bb6d376a35a05169a6bad52c6d589eac3bc3d676fc4ed6336e84d59fea
```

Thank your for your time to read this threat, please forgive me if i don't reply in correct format - I'm still new in here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet should work:

```
<%@ Page language="vb" debug=true %>
<%@ Import NameSpace = "System.Drawing" %>
<%

'-----------------------------------------------'
'QR-Code
'-----------------------------------------------'
Dim ZX As New ZXing.BarcodeWriter
Dim bmp As Bitmap
Dim options as ZXing.QrCode.QrCodeEncodingOptions

options = New ZXing.QrCode.QrCodeEncodingOptions
options.ErrorCorrection = ZXing.QrCode.Internal.ErrorCorrectionLevel.H
options.Height = 250
options.Width = 250
options.Margin = 0.9
options.PureBarcode = True

Zx.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
Zx.Options = options

bmp = Zx.Write("Test_1234")
bmp.Save("c:\inetpub\wwwroot\tester\qrcode.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
'-----------------------------------------------'
%>
```